# Source of teaching

Tags: sources-mekorot, quotations, tzaddikim

I read that “the works of the righteous are their offspring" is a "rabbinic teaching".  Is there a source, other than Chacham Tzvi 93?

Comment: [Rashi on Mishlei 13:22 has a relevant explanation](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.13.22?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in the comments, Rashi famously notes it in [Parshas Noach 6:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.6.9.1?vhe=Pentateuch_with_Rashi%27s_commentary_by_M._Rosenbaum_and_A.M._Silbermann,_1929-1934&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> שֶׁעִקַּר תּוֹלְדוֹתֵיהֶם שֶׁל צַדִּיקִים מַעֲשִׂים טוֹבִים
>
> That the offspring of righteous people are their good deeds

Rashi develops this concept from a Midrash in [Bereishis Rabbah 30:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Bereishit_Rabbah.30.6?lang=bi) where it says:

> פְּרִי צַדִּיק עֵץ חַיִּים, מָה הֵן פֵּרוֹתָיו שֶׁל צַדִּיק מִצְווֹת וּמַעֲשִׂים טוֹבִים
>
> "The fruit of the righteous is a tree of life" ([Mishlei 11:30](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.11.30?lang=bi)), what are the fruits of a tzaddik? Mitzvos and good deeds.

The expression used by Rashi is repeated in numerous places e.g. [Ohr HaChaim on Shemos 21:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_HaChaim_on_Exodus.21.4.9?vhe=On_Your_Way&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), The Shelah bring in [Torah Shebichsav, Bereishis, Torah Ohr 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Bereshit%2C_Torah_Ohr.5?vhe=Shenei_Luchot_HaBrit,_based_on_Amsterdam,_1698_ed._Part_III&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) as well as the [Akeidas Yitzchok 59:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Akeidat_Yitzchak.59.1.10?vhe=Akeidat_Yitzchak,_Pressburg_1849&lang=bi) to name but a few.

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to the answer already here, the idea is also found in the [Tanchuma for Noach](https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Tanchuma%2C_Noach.2.1). There's also a similar idea in the Zohar [(III:168a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Sh%27lach.25.202-204?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that Abraham and Sarah produced souls of converts while childless.